# Using find in macOS terminal with regex

Tags: macos, terminal, regex, find

I'm trying to search a folder containing variations on different image filenames:

```
1_2-300x224.jpg
1_2-600x449.jpg
1_2-600x600.jpg
1_2-768x575.jpg
1_2-802x600.jpg
1_2.jpg
```

The plan is to find and delete the files ending in 2-4 digits + 'x' + 2-4 digits. I can create this match on [Regexr](https://regexr.com/3m05u) using the expression `.*(\d{2,4}x\d{2,4}).jpg` (this expression highlights everything except for `1_2.jpg`).

However, running `find . -name ".*(\d{2,4}x\d{2,4}).jpg"` returns no results.

I'm flummoxed!

Comment: `-name` matches _globs_ not regexes.  If you want to match regexes, use `-regex`.  (And, if you don't like the default regex type, use `-regextype`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here. Firstly, as John mentioned, `-name` does sub-string matching with globs, you need to use `-regex`, and secondly, there are regular expression dialect incompatibilities. By default GNU find uses Emacs regular expressions and BSD find uses posix-basic regular expressions. If you have `find.info` installed you can read more about it here:

```
info find.info 'Reference' 'Regular Expressions' 'emacs regular expression'
```

Supported regular expression dialects can be found here:

```
info find.info 'Reference' 'Regular Expressions'
```

Here:

```
* findutils-default regular expression syntax::
* emacs regular expression syntax::
* gnu-awk regular expression syntax::
* grep regular expression syntax::
* posix-awk regular expression syntax::
* awk regular expression syntax::
* posix-basic regular expression syntax::
* posix-egrep regular expression syntax::
* egrep regular expression syntax::
* posix-extended regular expression syntax::
```

#### GNU find

You can make your expression work with `posix-extended` like this with GNU find:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*[0-9]{2,4}x[0-9]{2,4}.jpg'
```

Output:

```
./1_2-600x600.jpg
./1_2-802x600.jpg
./1_2-600x449.jpg
./1_2-300x224.jpg
./1_2-768x575.jpg
```

#### BSD find

I don't have access to BSD find, but I think this should work:

```
find -E . -regex '.*[0-9]{2,4}x[0-9]{2,4}\.jpg'
```

Comment: The final regex lacks a backslash before the literal dot and a closing quote at the end of the regex. My High Sierra MacOS (which is basically BSD) does not like the `.` before the `-E` option but reversing their order fixes that.